# Django, calling function in re.sub

Tags: python, regex, django

I have this line in my custom templatetag:

```
value = re.sub(r'(.*)\(bkz: (.*)\b\)',r'\1(bkz: <a href="/baslik/\2">\2</a>)',value)
```

I want to use the slugify function in my link to slugify the \2. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

`re.sub()` takes either a string or a function as second in parameter, you could define a function to do the things you want, below is a very trivial example

```
value = "aaa1aaa"
def slugifier(match_object):
    return 'X'

value = re.sub('\d+', slugifier, value)
>> 'aaaXaaa'
```

Just as a side note, `slugify` will escape the `\2` and produce an empty string.

Comment: This is not what I want. My code is a part of a template tag to change (bkz: sth) to a linked (bkz: sth) and the links are like /baslik/sth but this sth is not as it is. e.g. "Lorem ipsum" it goes to link /baslik/Lorem%20ipsum but the slugify slugs it as lorem-ipsum and my link is /baslik/lorem-ipsum and I want to direct the link created by template tag to this. Problem is not current only for whitespace. I use lots of non-English character in my project. My project is not English as well. How can I make this possible? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Well, a function like I described above is the way to go since you need to do multiple extractions and interpolations in order for it to work. There is no magic regex that does this for you. If you want to call `slugify` on parts of your regex then you need to do this and utilize the `match_object`.